# Email TCPDF Generated PDF file with php mail function

Tags: php, email, tcpdf

PDF file is being generated by tcpdf library but I cant attach it to email. It sends Email with an empty 1kb PDF file.

> ```
> $to = 'receiver@gmail.com';
> $subject = 'Receipt';
> $repEmail = 'info@gmail.com';
>
> $fileName = 'receipt.pdf';
> $fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'S');
> $attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
> $eol = PHP_EOL;
> $separator = md5(time());
>
> $headers = 'From: Sender <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
> $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
> $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
>
> $message = "--".$separator.$eol;
> $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
> $message .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
>
> $message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
> $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
> $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
>
> $message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
> $message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
> $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
> $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
> $message .= $attachment.$eol;
> $message .= "--".$separator."--";
>
> if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
> echo "Email sent";
> }
>
> else {
> echo "Email failed";
> }
> ```

I know its much easier with phpmailer but I'm required to do it with mail function and dont use any library.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $attachment = chunk_split($fileName);

Comment: Are you kidding me? $filename is 11 digit "name" for attachement

Comment: Please please please don't use PHP's built-in `mail()` function for sending attachments when there are excellent libraries like phpMailer available that will make your life so much easier. There really isn't a good reason not to use it, despite what you said in the question.

Comment: Use stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689567/sending-an-email-attachment-using-tcpdf

Comment: @Spudley I agree with you, I already done it with phpmailer but my boss want it with built in mail function

Comment: @Steve -- your boss is being foolish, and probably suffering from [NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). I'd like to know what reasons he's giving for not wanting to use phpMailer, because I'd be happy to shoot them all down in flames.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on link that **vodich** sent.

Your code is correct. You have to change one line:

```
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'S');
```

with

```
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
```

Comment: That's strange. I have copied your code, changed only this line and tested on my local machine and it works. I have received email with attachement with full content. I am using Ubuntu 12.04, sendmail installed for local testing ...