# TCPDF Laravel Email Attachments

Tags: php, email-attachments, tcpdf, laravel-5.1

TCPDF doesn't seem to be working well with either `$dest` option ("E" or "S") for sending PDF attachments in Laravel 5.1. Files are always corrupt with an error upon launching Acrobat Reader (error message: ... for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded). Decoding seems ok when I try another PDF generator like DOMPDF.

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF('P', 'in', 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->WriteHTML(view('emails.receipt_pdf', $receipt_data));
$attachment = $pdf->Output('Receipt - '.date("M-d-Y").'.pdf','E');

Mail::queue('emails.receipt_email', $receipt_data, function($message) use ($email, $attachment)
{
  $message->from('no-reply@website.com')
    ->to($email)
    ->subject('Receipt')
    ->attachData($attachment, 'Receipt.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried saving that file locally without sending it through email and is it fine in this case?

Comment: Yes, when I use `$dest` option "D" or "I", the PDF renders perfectly without corruption.

Comment: Try one thing, save the file to your local storage first and then try to send that file from storage. Not from TCPDF output.

Comment: Yes, when I save to filesystem using `$dest` option "F" and then attach using Laravel function `attach('filepath.name')` the file is not corrupt. Why is it that "E" or "S" seems to corrupt the file? Maybe I need to perform some kind of additional preparation to the string/attachment before sending it. I'd rather not save to filesystem before sending if possible.

Comment: For anyone looking for this, please see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689567/sending-an-email-attachment-using-tcpdf?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Just use "S" option while generating pdf. Email-related things will be done by Laravel.

Update

```
$attachment = $pdf->Output('Receipt - '.date("M-d-Y").'.pdf','E');
```

to

```
$attachment = $pdf->Output('Receipt - '.date("M-d-Y").'.pdf','S');
```

Additionally, if you are using queue() instead of send(), it will fail because of the attachment. To queue, write a job and send with the job queue.