# Generating a PDF with jsPDF and Attachment to mail

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, phpmailer, jspdf

I'm making an invoice system where users can insert their hours and hourly wage.
It's a basic system that generates invoices. The invoice is an HTML template.

For now, the invoice can be downloaded as .pdf with **jsPDF** on desktop versions.

I use the code:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('SendPDF');

        myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {

            let doc = new jsPDF('a4'); 

            doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdf'), function () {

              doc.save('<?php echo $factuurnummer;?>.pdf');
              output('SendPDF');

            });
        });
```

This will generate the PDF with the id **PDF**

What I would like to have is that this code will also run if the button sends to mail is pressed and generate a PDF and
include it into the PHP Mailer. $mail->AddAttachment = **file.pdf**;

Only I have no idea how I can do this.
Do someone have the experience to get this work.

PS. Is it possible to download the .pdf on mobile with jsPDF ?

thanks

Comment: How should that work? jsPDF runs in the browser, PHPMailer on your server. You could try to send the generated PDF file to the server by using an AJAX call and trigger the PHPMailer that way

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my code language is not that good. only know PHP and the basics of javascript. i'll dive into AJAX to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that it will be easier to generate PDF server-side using some PHP utility. The good choice (because it's free and open source) will be TCPDF https://tcpdf.org/. When You will generate a file with it You should be able to send it.

It seems, that this issue is already explained here: [sending an email attachment using TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689567/sending-an-email-attachment-using-tcpdf)